# Mismatch data when using different Base64 libraries

Tags: java

Currently using the Base64 conversion via the org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 library. This was implemented as part of some older token generation we have which works fine. We are currently trying to drop this library and stick to using Java 8's in built Base64 library under utils. But this doesn't work due to mismatched characters as follows. Is there a way to over come this (other than using regex which I definitely don't wanna mess with)? Please advice. Thank you.

```
String value1 = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(aByteArray);
String value2 = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(aByteArray);
```

Sample outcome when using the org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 library.

```
1111111111_22222_Some // value1
```

Sample outcome when using the java.util.Base64 library.

```
1111111111/22222/Some= // value2
```

Notice the difference between / and _ plus the missing = sign. In different tokens you will see differences such as + sign vs - sign and so on.

I have tried options without padding and setting StandardCharsets.UTF_8 for the byte array being passed in ending up with same  mismatched results.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table

Comment: What do you want to overcome. I suggest to use the `java.util.Base64` and be done with it.

Comment: Use java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(aByteArray) to generate the url safe base64 variant

Comment: @luk2302 I want to use util as mentioned above... but I can't due to the mismatch. After conversion, I am passing that value down to another micro service we have no control over managed by another team. This fails cos the value mismatches. They expect it to be in the commons.codec as shown above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(aByteArray);` creates a url safe base64 variant. (With _ and - as part of the encoding)

Using `java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(aByteArray);` will create the "standard" base64 with "/" "=" and "+" as part of the encoding. That would not be  url safe.

The Base64 class has a different encoder (`Base64.getUrlEncoder()`) for the url safe encoding variant:

```
java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(aByteArray)
```

Edit:

to remove the optional padding you can use

```
java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(aByteArray);
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Special characters match up but it comes with an equal sign at the end when the commons.codec doesn't.

Comment: @davidson this is called padding. Use `java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString()` if you do not want padding.